# Check checkbox input manually in click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom

So I have this code snippet that handles click events on input[type=checkbox]. What I want to achieve is to set `checked` property manually, depending on the if condition `scope.vm.checkedRows.indexOf(orderId) === -1` (here the false/true assignment is inverted to make the point), however it does not work.

```
link: function(scope, element) {
    element.on('click', '.csv-ignore input', function(event) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
            var orderId = angular.element(event.target).closest('tr').data('order-id')
            if (scope.vm.checkedRows.indexOf(orderId) === -1) {
                scope.vm.checkedRows.push(orderId);
                event.target.checked = false;
            } else {
                scope.vm.checkedRows.splice(scope.vm.checkedRows.indexOf(orderId), 1);
                event.target.checked = true;
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
}
```

Checkbox does not get checked/unchecked. What I found interesting is that then I comment out `return false` it works fine. However I initially added `return false` to prevent default behavior and check/uncheck checkbox manually. Do you know what is wrong with this code?

Comment: event.preventDefault() ? and remove return false?

Comment: tried, result is the same

Comment: why dont you do the opposite? unckeck it if its false or if its true leave it checked

Comment: it does not matter. I had the condition opposite just for testing

Comment: try return event.target.checked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can directly put an expression in `ng-checked` and do rest of the operation in the controller's on click. It will set checked value dynamically

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item" ng-checked="(vm.checkedRows.indexOf(orderId) !== -1)">
```